# How to properly send data to neo4j from .js file?

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to send data in neo4j database from .js file like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
var neo4j = require("neo4j-driver");
var driver = neo4j.driver(
  "neo4j://localhost",
  neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "something")
);

console.log(driver);

var session = driver.session({
  database: "neo4j",
  defaultAccessMode: neo4j.session.WRITE,
});

session
  .run("CREATE (n:User{nickname: 'Mama africa', reputation: '1789', authtoken: 'bad18eba1ff45jk7858b8ae88a77fa30', registered: 7/26/2022, postamount: 49 })")
  .subscribe({
    onKeys: (keys) => {
      console.log(keys);
    },
    onNext: (record) => {
        console.log(record.get("n"));
      },
      onCompleted: () => {
          session.close(); // returns a Promise
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          },
        });
      
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
      
      
      root.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

This is my React project and this .js file is in 'front' folder. So should I create separate folder
for example 'back' send data from 'front' to 'back' and therefore send data from 'back' to Database or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, front-end should never have to deal with the trouble of storing data, and it should not connect to a database directly. You should create a backend application in NodeJs, Java, or any language. And your frontend should interact with this backend-application via API's. You will send the data you want to store as API payload from Frontend to Backend application, and this backend application will connect to Neo4j and save data into it.